# Broken Pipe - Trying to display progress of dd on LCD display

Tags: python, gzip, subprocess, dd

I am trying to use Python to create a tool for imaging CF cards with a Raspberry Pi.

I had most of it working until I implemented compressed images with `dd`.

When I try and pipe the output of `gzip` to `dd`I lose the ability to poke the `dd` process and get a progress.

I have tried to use multiple sub processes but keep getting broken pipe or no such file errors.

Below is my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from Adafruit_CharLCD import Adafruit_CharLCD
import os
import sys
import time
import signal
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
lcd = Adafruit_CharLCD()
lcd.begin(16,2)
imgpth = '/home/pi/image/image_V11.img.gz'
line0 = ""
line1 = ""
q = 0
r = 0
s = 0

def lcdPrint(column, row, message, clear=False):
    if ( clear == True ):
        lcd.clear()

    lcd.setCursor(column, row)
    lcd.message(message)

lcd.clear()                 
lcdPrint(0, 0, 'Preparing Copy', True)
lcdPrint(0, 1, '')

gz = Popen(['gunzip -c /home/pi/image/image_V11.img.gz'], stdout=PIPE)
dd = Popen(['dd of=/dev/sda'],stdin=gz.stdout, stderr=PIPE)                     

filebyte = os.path.getsize(imgpth)                                  
flsz = filebyte/1024000 

while dd.poll() is None:                                        
    time.sleep(1)
    dd.send_signal(signal.SIGUSR1)
    while 1:                                            
        l = dd.stderr.readline()
    if '(' in l:                                            
        param, value = l.split('b',1)                           
        line1 = param.rstrip()                              
        r = float(line1)                                    
        s = r/1024000
        break
lcdPrint(0, 0, 'Copying....', True)
q = round(s/flsz*100, 2)                                
per = str(q)        

lcdPrint(0, 1, per + '% Complete',)

lcdPrint(0, 0, 'Copy Complete', True)   
time.sleep(1)
exit()
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Can you write the output of `gzip` to a file so that you're not piping `dd`'s input anymore?

Comment: I could but I am limited by size, I only have a 4GB SD card in the PI and the extracted dd image file would be 16GB, compressed the image is only 1.5GB.  So i need to be able to decompress on the fly.

Comment: The indentation is wrong near `while 1`. Check that SIGUSR1 doesn't kill `dd` (it shouldn't). What does `dd.poll()` return after `dd.stderr.readline()` failed?

Comment: The indentation in the code is correct(just didn't post it correctly, still learning this bit) dd.pol() and dd.stderr() dont't return anything as the code fails on the opening of dd as a subprocess.

Comment: use `['dd', 'of=/dev/sda']` instead of `['dd of=/dev/sda']` (same for `gunzip`)

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled across this question because I am doing exactly the same. My complete solution is here:

- http://github.com/jrmhaig/Bakery

I've tried to pick out some differences between what I have and yours that might show you the solution.

When starting the dd I redirected both stderr and stdout to the pipe.

```
dd = subprocess.Popen(['dd', 'of=/dev/sda', 'bs=1M'], bufsize=1, stdin=unzip.stdout, stdout=PIPE, stderr=STDOUT)
```

I don't think this should really make a difference. Everything you need should go to stderr but for some reason it appeared to get mixed up for me.

I use a separate thread to pick up the output from dd:

```
def read_pipe(out, queue):
    for line in iter(out.readline, b''):
        queue.put(str(line))
    out.close()

dd_queue = queue.Queue()
dd_thread = threading.Thread(target = read_pipe, args=(dd.stdout, dd_queue))
dd_thread.daemon = True
dd_thread.start()
```

Then when you call:

```
dd.send_signal(signal.SIGUSR1)
```

the output gets caught on dd_queue.

I also found that the uncompressed size of an gzipped file is stored in the last 4 bytes:

```
fl = open(str(imgpath), 'rb')
fl.seek(-4, 2)
r = fl.read()
fl.close()
size = struct.unpack('<I', r)[0]
```

os.path.getsize(imgpth) will only give you the compressed size so the percentage calculation will be wrong.